# Not able to run PowerShell on Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am running a PowerShell script which will stop a service on remote machine. When I am running it in PowerShell ISE then it is running fine. But when I am trying to run it from Jenkins hosted on my local machine it is giving me an error.

```
$SQL_agent="SQLSERVERAGENT"
$SQL_server="MSSQLSERVER"
$SQL_Agent_Service = Get-Service -Name $SQL_agent -ComputerName 192.168.48.44
$SQL_Server_Service = Get-Service -Name $SQL_server -ComputerName 192.168.48.44
 Stop-Service -InputObject $SQL_Agent_Service
  log("[SQLSERVERAGENT] shutdown complete.");
  Stop-Service -InputObject $SQL_Server_Service
  log("[MSSQLSERVER] shutdown complete.");
```

I am getting following error while running it from jenkins (jenkins is running on my local machine),

```
<pre>
D:\Eclipse_Repository\self_repo\jmallick\remote_db_backup.ps1:42 char:22
+ ... ent_Service = Get-Service -Name $SQL_agent -ComputerName 192.168.48.44
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SQLSERVERAGENT:String) [Get-Ser 
   vice], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell. 
   Commands.GetServiceCommand
Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'MSSQLSERVER'.At 
D:\Eclipse_Repository\self_repo\jmallick\remote_db_backup.ps1:43 char:23
+ ... er_Service = Get-Service -Name $SQL_server -ComputerName 192.168.48.44
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSSQLSERVER:String) [Get-Servic 
   e], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell. 
   Commands.GetServiceCommand
</pre>
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Please show the *full* error message as well as the actual command that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Jenkins is not running under the same account as of `MSSQLSERVER`
To change account for `jenkins` or `MSSQLSERVER` service

- Follow  go to services
- right click on Jenkins services and select **Properties**.
- Go to **Log On** tab
- Click on **This Account**
- In browse dialog select the user account you want o run Jenkins or Database server in

Comment: I am trying to stop a service on the remote machine and when I am running this script from local powershell ISE it is working fine but while running it from jenkins it is giving me error.
``